# how to catch dynamically specified exception

Tags: java, scala

Background is I have multiple exceptions I want to try on. can those be dynamically specified ?

```
def retryOn(e:Class[_])(n: Int)(block:() => Unit):Unit = {
    try {
        block()
    } catch {
        case e1: Throwable =>
            if (n > 1 && e1.isInstanceOf[e.type]) {
                retryOn(e)(n - 1)(block)
            }
            else throw e1
    }
}
```

from what tried above, this does not work, because the thrown e1 doesn't have any `debug` or type information at all.

Comment: y don't u use Try block instead of try{}catch{}, it contains everything u need

Comment: you can log or debug e1 before rethrowing it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.type` is `Class`, so `e1.isInstanceOf[e.type]` does not do what you want. You need `e.isInstance(e1)` instead there.